# Network Connection Checker via Reachability class swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I am trying to check the internet connection status via the Reachability.swift class which has written in swift 2.0. Here is the class code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability: NSObject {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
        let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)

    }
}
```

My question is this; When I am connected to cellular network this class could not recognise it which means isConnectedToNetwork() method returns false on my iPhone 5 device, not simulator. What could be the situation there? Please ant help would be appreciated, thanx...

Comment: For a working solution, take a look at https://github.com/ashleymills/reachability.swift

Comment: Thank you, I checked it before and it is an amazing work, but to use it I needed to change my data modal.

Comment: Thank you again! :) I managed to add a class method so that adapted it to my modal class...

Answer (score 1):

Along with Reachable and ConnectionRequired you need to check for this too.

```
let isWan = flags = .IsWWAN
```

If either of Reachable or IsWWAN is set you are connected to network. IsWWAN tells you if specified node name or address can be reached via a cellular connection, such as EDGE or GPRS.

Comment: let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
        let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired
        let isWan = flags == .IsWWAN
        return ((isReachable || isWan) && !needsConnection)

Comment: I changed the last lines of code as above, however it did not work. How should I change it?